# How to properly add the ampersand to the title tag

Tags: html, tags, html-entities

I have a title that includes the ampersand (&) but not sure how to add it properly so the web can read it.

if it write it like the

```
<title> something something & something </title>
```

when i inspect the page  i get

```
<title>something something &nbsp & &nbsp something </title>`
```

if I write it like this

```
<title> something something &amp; something </title>
```

when the page loads it simple doesn't change my html entity to & symbol.

Comment: How are you writing that? As HTML delivered direct to the browser? Or is there some client-side JS or server side programming involved? (including a CMS)

Comment: Where are you looking in the browser UI to determine that `nbsp` have been added or the entity isn’t being decided?

Comment: The page it self its react app  which loads data written in a json file .

Comment: I open the page on my local environment and also the page uploaded to the server.  The page in the server when i hover on the tab open i can see the ampersand is not decided and also when inspect the page i can the title tag that the ampersand is not decided

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I have the same question

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Using `&amp;` instead of `&` does it. You just need to clear your browser cache / force reload the site to see an immediate change.